# What is the viewport of a tree widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to locate an item of a tree widget.
Looking up in the doc, I got:

> ```
> QTreeWidgetItem * QTreeWidget::itemAt ( const QPoint & p ) const
> ```
>
> Returns a pointer to the item at the coordinates p. The coordinates are relative to the tree widget's `viewport()`.

The `viewport()` function does not give definition about `viewport` either.
So what is a tree widget's viewport ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTreeWidget inherits from [QAbstractScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#details), which is where the viewport is defined:

> QAbstractScrollArea is a low-level abstraction of a scrolling area. The area provides a central widget called the viewport, in which the contents of the area is to be scrolled (i.e, the visible parts of the contents are rendered in the viewport).

The viewport is essentially the visible part of the tree.